# How to change package name of WhatsApp

Tags: reverse-engineering, whatsapp

i found that many devs are changing package name of whatsapp like whatsmapp and og can anyone help me in this

How can i do that ?

Or any guide to learn this smali values and how it works

Comment: this post [on xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2760965) might me useful